# How to fit a statistical model with a one hot encoded variable

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have my data frame that initially looked like this:

```
 item_id              title     user_id   gender   .....
0        1   Toy Story (1995)   308        M
1        4  Get Shorty (1995)   308        M
2        5     Copycat (1995)   308        M
```

Than I ran a mixed effects regression, which worked fine:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

md = smf.mixedlm("rating ~ C(gender) + C(genre) + C(gender)*C(genre)", data, groups=data["user_id"])
mdf=md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

However, afterwards I did a one hot encoding on the gender variable and the dataframe became like this:

```
 item_id              title     user_id   gender_M     gender_F   .....
0        1   Toy Story (1995)   308        1              0
1        4  Get Shorty (1995)   308        1              0
2        5     Copycat (1995)   308        1              0
```

Would it be correct to run the model like this  (changing gender with gender_M and gender_F)? Is it the same? Or is there a better way?

```
md = smf.mixedlm("rating ~ gender_M + gender_F + C(genre) + C(gender)*C(genre)", data, groups=data["user_id"])
mdf=md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

Comment: For Ordinary Least Squares (`smf.ols`), categorical features are replaced by dummy variables. So I would say that behind the scenes, `mixedlm` does the same. Creating dummy variables yourself may be useful with modules such as `sklearn` that won't do it themselves, but for `statsmodels` it is not necessary.

Comment: What you've done in the second won't be totally correct. `C()` creates a full basis of dummies with **one leave out group**. If you include all the dummies then that set of features is perfectly collinear with the constant. So in the second regression you should omit `gender_F` and you should get the same result.

Comment: I.e. in your second regression you should see some warning at the bottom of the model summary, along the lines of "The smallest eigenvalue is 3.18e-30. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular"